# Пунктуационные вопросы в статье (2)

Tags: пунктуация

*Проблема настолько острая, что требуется предметное осмысление роли руководителя в системе противодействия коррупции, его задач, правовых, административных и этических рычагов воздействия на свои коллективы*.
"Настолько" нужно писать слитно или раздельно?

*...по(...), по(...), по(...), по разъяснительной работе с каждым сотрудником, а главное по определению в своей организации коррупциогенных очагов и нейтрализации коррупциогенных рисков.*
Нужно ли тире после "а главное"?

*Наметить пути совершенствования антикоррупционной борьбы на основе усиления роли руководителя как менеджера и, главное, как лидера.*
Верно ли расставлены знаки?

*Противодействие коррупции – деятельность по выявлению,  ликвидации первопричин коррупционных нарушений и воспрепятствовании коррупционерам в пользовании незаконно-полученными благами, а также созданию возможностей для (государственного) лица, принимающего решения, выйти из коррупционной ситуации, и по созданию системы личной ответственности руководителя за коррупционные действия его подчинённых.*
Верно ли расставлены знаки?

*Мы провели группировку общих и отличительных характеристик менеджера и лидера на основе работ крупнейших теоретиков классической и современной науки об управлении, таких как Файоль, Тейлор, Адизес, Деминг.*
Нужно ли двоеточие после "таких как"?

*Читателю будет интересно узнать как мы классифицировали и сгруппировали массив нормативно-правовых актов антикоррупционного российского законодательства, исходя из их направленности и предмета регулирования.*
Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Comment: Точка в конце предложения — это тоже знак препинания (пунктуация). Не забывайте про неё.

Comment: Лучше разбить этот вопрос на множество мелких. Так правильней с точки зрения целей этого сайта и для вас лучше - скорее получите ответы.

Comment: "Воздействия на свои коллективы". Сочетание слов, проблемное по многим причинам. Что это за понятие такое: руководитель и его коллективы? Даже если поставить в единственном числе (руководитель и его коллектив), оно не соответствует стилистике данной статьи.

Comment: "Нейтрализация рисков" — тоже проблемное словосочетание. Риски можно уменьшать или увеличивать, а нейтрализавать можно, например, опасные факторы.

Comment: "Наметить пути совершенствования антикоррупционной борьбы на основе усиления роли руководителя как менеджера и, главное, как лидера". Сильный лидер - основа борьбы с коррупцией? Вы именно это хотели сказать?

Comment: 'Kлассической и современной науки об управлении". Сомневаюсь в наличии **двух** таких наук.

Comment: "Классифицировали и сгруппировали массив". Не уверен, что массив поддается классификации и группировке. Элементы массива (правовые акты) - да. Слово "массив" здесь кажется вообще лишним, употребленным "для красного словца"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Здесь **настолько** — наречие, пишется слитно.
2. **А главное**
   Союз + вводное слово. Указывает на то, что говорящий намерен высказать важную, особенно существенную мысль. Если слово «главное» можно изъять или переместить, то оно выделяется с двух сторон знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Если же исключить или переставить слово «главное» нельзя (как в нашем случае), то запятая между «а» и «главное» не ставится. Перед союзом «а» обычно ставится запятая или (в зависимости от контекста) другой знак препинания.

Вы **должны** поставить или тире, или запятую — выбор за вами.

3. Все правильно.
   Возможен и такой вариант:
   *...на основе усиления роли руководителя — как менеджера и как лидера.*
4. *Противодействие коррупции – деятельность по выявлению, ликвидации первопричин коррупционных нарушений и воспрепятствовани**ю** коррупционерам в пользовании **незаконно полученными** благами, а также **по** созданию для (государственного) лица, принимающего решения, **возможностей выхода** из коррупционной ситуации и по созданию системы личной ответственности руководителя за коррупционные действия его подчинённых.*
   Перед последним союзом "и" запятая не нужна.
5. Все правильно, двоеточие не нужно.
   Оно было бы необходимо в такой "конструкции":
   *...на основе работ крупнейших теоретиков классической и современной науки об управлении: Файоля, Тейлора, Адизеса, Деминга.*
6. Запятая перед "как" нужна.